# How to extract texts from multiple textnodes within an element using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

I have an element found through BeautifulSoup that (HTML) looks like this:

```
  <div class="ListingData">
    <span id="l_Contract" class="contract">Vendita Residenziale</span><br />
    New York<br />
    Appartamento<br />
    <strong>Prezzo:</strong>
    &euro; 100.000/200.000
    - <strong>Metri quadri:</strong>
    130/170
    </div>
```

And I need to get in one variable **Vendita Residenziale**, in another **New York**,in another **Appartamento** , in another **100.000/200.000** (not the strong tag) and in the last one **130/170**.

I can extract the span tag text doing:

```
x = ele.find('span', attrs = {'class': 'contract'}).get_text()
```

but I'm struggling to get the other information, I tried to:

```
y = ele.find('div', attrs = {'class':'ListingData'}).get_text().replace("\n","").strip()
```

but this gives me all the div content and that's okay but I need to get the individual lines of information like a "result[1]" for New York, "result[2]" for Appartamento and so on. Is there a method?

Answer (score 0):

I used a mix of BeautifulSoup4 and Regular Expression, you can toy with the  [regex](https://regex101.com/).

```
a=bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt,'html.parser')
a.findAll(id="l_Contract")[0].text # Vendita Residenziale
p=re.compile("<br />").split(txt)
p[1] # "New York"
p[2] # "Appartamento"
re.compile("&euro;\s+([0-9.]+\/[0-9.]+)\s+-\s+<strong>").search(txt).group(1) #100.000/200.000
```

Another way would be simply doing this

```
a.findAll(class_="ListingData")[0].text
#Output
'\nVendita Residenziale\n    New York\n    Appartamento\nPrezzo:\n    € 100.000/200.000\n    - Metri quadri:\n    130/170\n    '
```

Wich is easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Since all text you want is in the `<div>` tag, seems the easiest way would be to get the `<div>` text, and split the text on newlines `'\n'` into a `result` list:

```
result = [e.strip() for e in ele.div.text.strip().split('\n')]

>>> result
[u'Vendita Residenziale', u'New York', u'Appartamento', u'Prezzo:', u'\u20ac 100.000/200.000', u'- Metri quadri:', u'130/170']
```

which can then be indexed as desired:

```
for n, res in enumerate(result):
    print(f'result[{n}] = {res}')

result[0] = Vendita Residenziale
result[1] = New York
result[2] = Appartamento
result[3] = Prezzo:
result[4] = € 100.000/200.000
result[5] = - Metri quadri:
result[6] = 130/170
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [navigable string and .contents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '''
<div class="ListingData">
    <span id="l_Contract" class="contract">Vendita Residenziale</span><br />
    New York<br />
    Appartamento<br />
    <strong>Prezzo:</strong>
    &euro; 100.000/200.000
    - <strong>Metri quadri:</strong>
    130/170
    </div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
item1 = soup.select_one('#l_Contract').text
items = soup.select_one('.ListingData').contents
results = []
for item in items:
    if isinstance(item, NavigableString) and item.strip():
        results.append(item.strip())

item2 = results[0]
item3 = results[1]
item4 = results[2]

print(item1, ',', item2, ',', item3, ',', item4)
```

Answer (score 0):

not really a bs4 issue here, the other data you want isn't inside of span tags, extract your data based on string observations

```
sp=sp.find('div',id='onesiwant')
for div in sp:
    all=div.text.strip()
    #now you can split('\n') 
     html=str(div)
     get the stuff out of span
        now split by '<br>' tags
```

your asking how to use bs4 to get data out of text in between tags or seperated by \n, so bs4 here is not necessary, just string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) alone can extract all the required texts and you can use the following solution:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "div[@class='ListingData']")))
text_Vendita_Residenziale = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "div[@class='ListingData']/span[@class='contract' and contains(@id='Contract')]")))
text_NewYork = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', element).strip()
text_Appartamento = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', element).strip()
text_100_200 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[8].textContent;', element).strip()
text_130_170 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', element).strip()
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I run this code it raise a TimeoutException on the first line (element = ...), I imported everything like this: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`

Comment: _...TimeoutException on the first line (element )..._ means the desired element wasn't uniquely identified even after _WebDriverWait_. Can you update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML?